# How can i get the fetched record in route model nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting the fetch records on console, but I want to access on route page.

```
module.exports.getcoin_info = function(err,callback){
  var results = [];

  coin_model.find(function(err,teams){
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }

    results.push(teams);    

    console.log(results);
  });   
}
```

route page in this function I am not getting records. Please guide me how it will proceed if there are any another way for the same please guide me.

```
monogoose_user.getcoin_info(function(err, results) {   
  if (err) {
    console.log('here');
  } else {
    console.log(results);   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the following?

```
module.exports.getcoin_info = function(callback) {
    coin_model.find(function(err, teams) {
        callback(err, teams);
    });
}
```

This way you will be able to access both the error and teams in your callback.

Basically you are just calling the callback function with 2 parameters (`err` and `teams`) after it's done searching the DB.

Comment: @RiyaSinghal Awesome! Glad to hear it. Happy coding!!